# Spring: injecting @RequestBody into @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to populate `requestScopedBean.userDetails` when my controller's `update(...)` gets executed / before it is executed.

In my spring web project I have java based `MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in which I have:

```
@Bean(name = "requestScopedBean")
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean() {
    return new RequestScopedBean();
}
```

While in `RequestScopedBean.java` :

```
public class RequestScopedBean {

    public @Autowired UserDetails userDetails;

    public void setUserDetails(UserDetails pUserDetails){
        userDetails = pUserDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + (userDetails != null) ;
    }
}
```

And `UserDetails.java`

```
public class UserDetails {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And I have `UsersController.java` containing :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Scope("request")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean;

     @RequestMapping(
         value = {"{uid}" }, 
         method = RequestMethod.PUT, 
         produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @PathVariable String uid,
        @RequestBody UserDetails pUserDetails
    ) throws Exception {

        // LOCATION 1

        // return ResponseEntity;
    }
}
```

What can I do such that at `LOCATION 1`, `requestScopedBean.userDetails` holds variable `pUserDetails` received in this functions as parameter.

I am looking for some **setter-based dependency injection** or **some factory method based injection** though please do advise if some other method is more suitable. Thanks

Comment: _"I want to populate requestScopedBean.userDetails"_, _"I am looking for some setter-based dependency injection"_ Then call `setUserDetails`. I don't see a problem.

Comment: currently at LOCATION 1 requestScopedBean.userDetails remains null

Comment: Because you don't call `setUserDetails`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to keep the UserDetails object which came from Request, just set the object to requestScopedBean.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Scope("request")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean;

     @RequestMapping(
         value = {"{uid}" }, 
         method = RequestMethod.PUT, 
         produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(
        @PathVariable String uid,
        @RequestBody UserDetails pUserDetails
    ) throws Exception {

        requestScopedBean.setUserDetails(pUserDetails);

        // return ResponseEntity;
    }
}
```

Apart from this, I advice you not to Autowire in your UserDetails object in RequestScopedBean

```
public class RequestScopedBean {

    public UserDetails userDetails;

    public void setUserDetails(UserDetails pUserDetails){
        userDetails = pUserDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + (userDetails != null) ;
    }
}
```

Let me know, what is the problem you are facing with this approach.

Comment: In a controller with more parameters to be set in requestScopedBean I will have to write a long list of setter instructions. In a more complex scenario I will need to populate requestScopedBean with 'uid' and so on... hence I was thinking about autowiring instead.

Comment: The pUserDetails in request param is already populated with values, you dont need to call setters of pUserDetails to set values.

Comment: Secondly, if you are thinking about so many path variables like uid and you want to keep them in requestScopedBean then for cleaner approach I suggest you to create a new class containing all the params and use it as ResponseBody. Because if you use path variable then you have to call setters. there is no better approach