# How can I inject @RequestBody object(value object) to Spring Service layer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

How can I inject @RequestBody object(value object) to Spring Service layer?

I want to Inject(Autowired)objects what come from request body values.

**HelloController**

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

(….)

@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(
        @RequestBody UserRequestBodyDto userDto,
        HttpServletResponse response){

    return null;
}
```

**UserRequestBodyDto**

```
@Data
public class UserRequestBodyDto{
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @AutoWired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRequestBodyDto userDto){
      (….)
    }

}
```

In that case, how can I inject UserRequestBodyDto objects into service layer?

Add 'setUserDto' method to UserService is the best way?
or If
convert dto to entity is the best way to inject objets,
how can I manage many of same classes between dto class and entity class?

+a) In my opinion, make a `RequestScopedBean` is bad way.

ref: [Spring: injecting @RequestBody into @Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737966/spring-injecting-requestbody-into-bean)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to `@AutoWired` a request object? I seems completely unnecessary while doing operation with a request object cause, it will change on every new request.

So you can do operation with request object in the service layer method.

```
 public UserServiceImpl(UserRequestBodyDto userDto){
      (….)//do operation with userDto here.
 }
```

Or, I you really need to `@AutoWire` the request object then declare `UserRequestBodyDto userDto` in service layer with `@AutoWired` annotation. And when the service layer method executes just set the values to `this.userDto`.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    @AutoWired
    private UserRequestBodyDto userDto;

    @AutoWired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRequestBodyDto userDto){
      this.userDto = userDto;//Here, setting value of userDto to this.userDto
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I don't know Beans are always managed by singleton.